# Trouble figuring out how to close tags using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, recursion, foreach

I'm building a category manager via database. The following PHP generates the code I'll paste below that:

```
function generate_menu($parent, $menu_array, $result = NULL)
{
    $has_childs = FALSE;

    foreach($menu_array as $key => $value):
        if ($value['parent'] == $parent):
            $result .= '<li id="list_'.$value['id'].'" class="item">';
            $result .= '<div class="item">' . $value['name'] . '</div>';

            if ($has_childs):
                $has_childs = FALSE;
                $result .= '<ol>';
            else:
                $has_childs = TRUE;
                $result .= '</li>';
            endif; 

            $result .= $this->generate_menu($key, $menu_array);
        endif;
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}
```

And here's the HTML it generates:

```
<li id="list_11" class="item">
    <div class="item">Real Estate</div>
</li>
<li id="list_12" class="item">
    <div class="item">Home Improvements</div>
    <ol>
        <li id="list_13" class="item">
            <div class="item">Interior</div>
        </li>
        <li id="list_14" class="item">
            <div class="item">Exterior</div>
            <ol>
                <li id="list_15" class="item">
                    <div class="item">Exterior Subcat</div>
                </li>
```

So I'm able to close the `<li>` tag when it's a parent, but if it's an item with a parent, an `<ol>` enters the equation. That's when I don't know how to close them. I'm not sure where to put the `</li>` and `</ol>`. Everything I've tried just doesn't work.

Here's how it *should* look:

```
<li id="list_11" class="item">
    <div class="item">Real Estate</div>
</li>
<li id="list_12" class="item">
    <div class="item">Home Improvements</div>
    <ol>
        <li id="list_13" class="item">
            <div class="item">Interior</div>
        </li>
        <li id="list_14" class="item">
            <div class="item">Exterior</div>
            <ol>
                <li id="list_15" class="item">
                    <div class="item">Exterior Subcat</div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the code for passing the array and generating the menu:

```
$query = $this->db->get('categories');

foreach($query->result_array() as $row):
    $menu_array[$row['id']] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'parent' => $row['parent'], 'id' => $row['id']);
endforeach;

echo '<ol class="sortable">';
echo $this->tasks->generate_menu(0, $menu_array);
echo '</ol>';
```

And here's the print_r of $menu_array:

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [name] => Real Estate
            [parent] => 
            [id] => 11
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => Home Improvements
            [parent] => 
            [id] => 12
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [name] => Interior
            [parent] => 12
            [id] => 13
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [name] => Exterior
            [parent] => 12
            [id] => 14
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [name] => Exterior Subcat
            [parent] => 
            [id] => 15
        )

)
```

Comment: Why are you passing `$result` to the function as an argument? And why are you using the alternative syntax? Also, what does the array look like?

Comment: Not sure why I did that with $result, but I have since moved it into the function. That's isn't the problem though. I will append my post with the array, which, again, isn't the problem.

Comment: It's not the problem, but it's a part of the solution. If you want us to understand your problem, you need to tell us 5 things: What do you want? What have you tried? What are you inputting? What are you expecting? What are you getting? You've told us 4 of those.

Comment: Don't you mean six? "And why are you using the alternative syntax?"

Comment: Heh, no that's really as a side note. Alternative syntax is meant usually for printing large blocks of HTML in between the PHP blocks (to prevent awkward `<?php } ?>` out of nowhere).

Comment: I didn't know that, but makes sense. I've always used it because I think it looks nice.

Comment: What I meant by show us the array, is take the complete array, `print_r()` it properly, and display the output here.

Comment: I have edited the original post.

Comment: In the foreach loop you sholud check whether the <li> tag is a parent or it's an item with a parent. If you want to implement this method, you should add a boolean flag which will be an indicator for <li>  - parent / tag with a parent. Once you do it,  you'll be able to know when <ol> tags should be added in the right place. Hope you had found this answer helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this one out. I was complicating things a bit.

```
function generate_menu($parent, $menu_array, $result = NULL)
{       
    foreach($menu_array as $key => $value):
        if ($value['parent'] == $parent):
            $result .= '<li id="list_'.$value['id'].'" class="item">';
            $result .= '<div class="item">' . $value['name'] . '</div>';
            $result .= '<ol>';
            $result .= $this->generate_menu($key, $menu_array);
            $result .= '</li></ol>';
        endif;
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Your closing li and ol need to be the other way round :) Apart from that, as long as you don't have a lot of data to work with (and don't mind the empty ol's) this is a good solution I think. If the menu array becomes very large, you may get performance issues as you iterate through the whole array once per item.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a recursive function properly, the array of values would need to reflect the hierarchy like so:

```
array(
[11] => "Real Estate",
[12] => array(
    [0] => "Home Improvements",
    [13] => "Interior",
    [14] => "Exterior"
    ),
[15] => "Exterior Subcat"
)
```

The function could now iterate through 11, adding a list item normally. At 12 it would encounter an array rather than a string (use `gettype($value)`), so instead of adding a list item it would call itself again - passing the array it just found as the argument. This allows in theory for an unlimited number of levels.

```
function make_menu($menu_array) {

    $result = "<ol>";

    foreach($menu_array as $k=>$v)
    {
        $result .= '<li id="list_'.$k.'" class="item">';

        if(gettype($v) == 'array')
        {
            $result .= '<div class="item">' . $v[0] . '</div>';
            unset($v[0]);
            $result .= make_menu($v);
        }
        elseif(gettype($v) == 'string')
        {
            $result .= '<div class="item">' . $v . '</div>';
        }

        $result .= '</li>';
    }
    $result .= "</ol>";
    return $result;
}
```